# Why openssl insist on requiring a passphrase on genrsa command?

Tags: openssl

Issue command:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsaprivatekey-nake.pem  -des3 1024
```

If not providing a passphrase(just press enter when requested), it keeps saying:

```
Enter pass phrase for rsaprivatekey-nake.pem:
3073726088:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:ui_lib.c:869:You must type in 4 to 8191 characters
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Env: openSUSE 11.4, openssl 1.0.0c

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because you are *asking it to* encrypt the private key by giving the `-des3` option.

If you don't want your key to be protected by a password, remove the `-des3` option from the command line.

Comment: note that `-des3` can be the implicit default option `-des3         encrypt private keys with triple DES (default)`... 

so keep calm if you have the same prompt without asking openssl explicitly... same option to disable of course `-nodes` (read `no DES`)

Comment: my version of openssl genrsa doesn't have a -nodes option.  Just leave off the -des3 or any other encryption option in that case.  From [link]https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/genrsa.html: `If none of these options is specified no encryption is used`

Comment: in my case I need to add `-nodes`

Comment: -nodes has been replaced with -noenc